# Passing the parent ViewModel instance as the CommandParameter for DataTemplate's Button command

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have a ListBox with `ItemsSource` set to a `Collection<ItemViewModel>`.
The ListBox has a **DataTemplate** defined, to display ViewModel instances in a nice way.

In the DataTemplate, I have a Button which is bound to a *MainViewModel command*, **not** a command defined in the `ItemViewModel` class.

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=mainViewModel,
                          Path=ProcessClickForThisItem}">
```

The desired behavior is for the button to call the mainViewModel's command and tell the method behind it, where the button click comes from - from which `ItemViewModel` instance.

I'm guessing the `CommandParameter` property can be used here. However, how do I reference the parent viewmodel instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Button parent will be `ListBoxItem` and it's `DataContext` will be instance of `ItemViewModel` which is of your interest.

You need `RealtiveSource` to get ListBoxItem. This is how you use `CommandParameter`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=mainViewModel,
                         Path=ProcessClickForThisItem}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                   AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}">
```

Comment: Awesome! I was slowly walking around approaches similar to this, but not quite this, and not quite working. Thanks for the clarification :)